# When Excel addin runs 'RunPython()', Workbook.caller() raise an error

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I found xlwings is a very exceptional project as a bridge between Excel and Python. So I am applying it to my excel addin development.

But I got some problem.

When excel addin calls python module, the Workbook.caller() does not return Workbook object(addin workbook itself)! Just Error!

Instead of Workbook.caller(), I make use of 'Workbook() passing by 'Current ActiveWorkbook's name'. But in that case, I'm afraid that 'Optimize_connection= true' may raise memory garbage issue!

(If 'IsAddin' property in VBA is off, then it runs very well)

Is there anyone to help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using `OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION = True` ?

Comment: No, not yet. But I need the option in case my vba addin calls python module frequently.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Name'

Comment: (I put the error message below in detail.)  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\MEMPIRE\woods\Olive108\Lib\Operator.py", line 17, in addnumbers
    wb = Workbook.caller()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 88, in caller
    return cls(xl_workbook=xl_workbook)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.active_sheet = Sheet.active(wkb=self)

Comment: File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 282, in active
    return cls(xlplatform.get_worksheet_name(xlplatform.get_active_sheet(xl_workbook)), wkb)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 60, in get_worksheet_name
    return xl_sheet.Name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Name'

Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but the solution may be as simple as replacing `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` when using the xlwings VBA module as add-in. Anyhow, I've created an issue to get this resolved: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/153

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. You mean I have to use 'ActiveWorkbook' instead of ThisWorkbook in VBA Module(addin)? But In excel addin, **ActiveWorkbook** indicate 'Current Opened Workbook(not addin workbook. because addin is hidden)'. However, **ThisWorkbook** indicate 'addin Workbook itself'. I'm afraid i misunderstood your answer..

Comment: So the xlwings VBA module sends over a couple of parameters from the Excel Workbook that you want Python to work with, like e.g. the Workbook name. This is currently done by `ThisWorkbook.FullName`, since it expects the VBA module to be in every Workbook you want to setup with xlwings. Changing this to an addin, you need to change these things to `ActiveWorkbook.FullName` so that the correct file name will be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work-around to get the Excel add-in that's calling Python code:

```
import mock
import platform
import xlwings
from   xlwings import Workbook

def get_add_in():
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        # Workbook.caller crashers instead of returning the add-in
        get_add_in_caller_on_windows()
    else:
        return Workbook.caller()

@mock.patch('xlwings.Sheet.active')
def get_addin_caller_on_windows(mock_active):
    # The xlwings.Sheet.active method is mocked because the add-in has no
    # active worksheet.
    xl_app = xlwings.xlplatform.get_xl_apps()[0]
    return Workbook(xl_workbook=xl_app.ThisWorkbook)
```

It works with Python 3.4 and xlwings 0.6.4 on:

- Windows 8.1 with Excel 2013
- OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) with Excel for Mac 2011