# xlwings module.py call python from excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, vba

I keep receiving this error while trying to call the [module.py](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html#call-python-with-runpython) file from excel

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\ana\module.py", line 6, in rand_numbers
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
AttributeError: type object 'Workbook' has no attribute 'caller'
```

When I replace `wb = Workbook.caller()` with `wb = Workbook()` I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\ana\module.py", line 11, in rand_numbers
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1341, in mtrand.RandomState.randn (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:11537)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1454, in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:11839)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 142, in mtrand.cont0_array (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:1867)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Alternatively [scenario 2], I am able to call a python file from excel while using [this sample code](http://docs.xlwings.org/quickstart.html#interact-with-excel-from-python)

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
wb = Workbook()  # Creates a connection with a new workbook
#wb = Workbook.caller()
Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
Range('A2').value = [['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]
Range('A13').table.value  # or: Range('A1:C2').value
Sheet(1).name
chart = Chart.add(source_data=Range('A2').table)
```

However the call in excel only works with `wb = Workbook()` and not `wb = Workbook.caller()`

I am aware of [this API documentation update](http://docs.xlwings.org/whatsnew.html?highlight=optimized#id4)

**module.py**

```
import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def rand_numbers():
    """ produces std. normally distributed random numbers with shape (n,n)"""
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    n = Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
    Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value = rand_num
```

**VBA code**

```
Sub MyMacro()
    RunPython ("import module; module.rand_numbers()")
End Sub
```

**testing.py** (test example code - scenario 2)

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
wb = Workbook()  # Creates a connection with a new workbook
#wb = Workbook.caller()
Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
Range('A2').value = [['Foo 1', 'Foo 2', 'Foo 3'], [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]]
Range('A13').table.value  # or: Range('A1:C2').value
Sheet(1).name
chart = Chart.add(source_data=Range('A2').table)
```

**VBA code**

```
Sub MyMacro()
    RunPython ("import testing") 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you put the exact code you are running (both `module.py` and the VBA Macro? Also, is the python file in the same directory as the excel file?

Comment: added the code; yes ALL files are in the same directory

Comment: I did a search and replace for `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521702/when-excel-addin-runs-runpython-workbook-caller-raise-an-error but the code still came up short

Comment: Hmmm, and you're running the latest version of xlwings? I just tried it and it worked for me with version `0.3.2`. I'm using a Mac with all the out-of-the-box settings and just did a fresh install of xlwings using `pip`.

Comment: It really looks like you're operating on an old version of xlwings: Open a command prompt, type `python`, then `import xlwings` and `xlwings.__version__`.

Comment: I had downloaded anaconda and while xlwings ships with conda, I had to update xlwings as the default version shipped was not the latest, `conda install xlwings`

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error exactly with xlwings version 0.3.4 and winpython 2.7.9.4 when cell B1 in spreadsheet is left as a null, hence the error "an integer is required". So passing in the dimension of the numpy array through cell B1 will fix the problem in the first set of example code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mymodule.py", line 8, in rand_numbers
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1352, in mtrand.RandomState.randn (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:13134)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1465, in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:13467)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 145, in mtrand.cont0_array (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:1810)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: that's not an answer, is it ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra It's an answer now.

Comment: depending on your version of NumPy, you might also need to wrap `Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value` with an `int()`, the docs have been upgraded acordingly.