# Xlwings: run python from Excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

First, I should say that this code was ok last wee (that means it was running and no problems).

I don't know why, but:
1 - I have a Excel file on OneDrive. This file have the xlwings imported and this function on VBA:

```
Sub CallSAP()
'Run the Python Script
RunPython ("import LoadSAP; LoadSAP.ScriptSAP()")    
End Sub
```

2 - The LoadSAP.py was placed on the same path of the Excel file.

This week, I have the issue:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LoadSAP'

Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

It's similar to [xlwings module.py call python from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921933/xlwings-module-py-call-python-from-excel)

3 - So, I tried to execute the LoadSAP.py, I maked a copy on the C://Documents, I runned the function on Jupyter notebook file, and miraculously the Excel now recognize the LoadSAP.
Ps.: I need to know how to fix this issue because I have the same to the loadMaps.py function.

4 - Now, running on the Excel, a new problem appears: the program doesn't recognize the path of OneDrive, and it suggest to change to the link https.

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The syntax of the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect: 'https://.../Documents/.../Excel file.xlsm'
```

5 - After I did the change like demanded on item 4, on this line code (this read na other Excel file to push some data)

gerder = read_excel(path_gerder + file_gerder, sheet_name='Base')

I have 2 issues:

Sometimes it returns:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Sometimes it returns:

```
No such file: 'https://.../Documents/.../gerder file.xls'
```

Ps.: If I use the link to the file on the brownser, it's downloaded.

I have many singulars issues and it worked well just one week ago: the Excel recognized all the *.py, the program readed all the Excel file directly of OneDrive, etcs etcs. So if you have any idea or suggestion, I open to try.

Comment: OneDrive currently requires you to set the PYTHONPATH, see: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1275

Comment: This is unconnected with xlwings, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

First, like Felix Zumstein commented:

1 - Set the PYTHONPATH on Excel file: [How to set the PYTHONPATH on Excel by xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html)

2 - I don't know exactly why, but xlwings don't recognize the OneDrive path like `'C:/.../Documents/.../Excel file.xlsm'`. So, this error appears:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The syntax of the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect: 'https://.../Documents/.../Excel file.xlsm'
```

At the same time, the funcion read_excel of Pandas and others functions don't recognize the OneDrive path like `'https://.../Documents/.../Excel file.xlsm'`. And this error should appear:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Solution: I used the path like `'https://.../Documents/.../Excel file.xlsm'` to any xlwings functions. For the others functions, I used the path: `'C:/.../Documents/.../Excel file.xlsm'`.